# Is the Samsung S-pen input the same as your fingers?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I have no actual Galaxy Note on-hand and no access to such device so
I would like to ask if the S-Pen behaves the same way as a Finger on a SurfaceView?
Basing from the behavior of S-Pen SDK samples when run on an emulator, it seems that the S-Pen's input is the same with finger inputs only that it is very precise. (noticing that when run on the emulator, its impossible to detect if input came from a finger or S-Pen since touch input is emulated via the mouse cursor)

I'd like to confirm if the gestures I can do with my finger is also doable using the S-Pen?
If this is the case, is it safe to say that the S-Pen is comparable to a very thin finger?
The only difference it can make, is that when an app is coded with specific functionality using the SDK that samsung provides?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the international Samsung Note (still waiting on ICS). But your question would be [better served by one of the xda developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1346).

Using the S Memo app to add a memo, selecting the pen input option, I can write a note using my finger.  The stroke is thin, as it would be for a pen...

I can use the pen to interact with anything on the screen, as if it were my finger.  But the pen can not interact with the capacitative buttons, nevermind the physical ones.

Comment: lol, i didnt expect the samples to work on a device without S-pen support, but yeah it did, i just tried it with the Galaxy S and lines come out as expected...

Comment: The S Pen also has 256 levels of pressure sensitivity. So better and more precise pressure inputs for that capacitive screen

Answer (score 1):

As it will be easier for everyone to spot an answer and not a comment, here's an explanation from samsung developers themselves:

[S Pen behavior on SurfaceView - http://developer.samsung.com/](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SPenSDK&messageId=152294&startPage=27&curPage=29)

Comment: While this is a valuable link, it would be better as an edit to my previous post, as there is no answer, only a link. You are correct that it shouldnt be an answer, but it shouldn't be a comment either.  it serves as an expansion and confirmation of my earlier answer, so it is an appropriate edit. I do appreciate the insight from the developer as to the inended use of the API functions, however.

Answer (score 0):

The s pen works with the Wacom digitizer in the Note devices. This allows for precision, pressure sensitivity (256 levels on my Note II),  and hover events. These are pointer events, not touch or mouse/click events at the OS level.